# Update an XML file in Google Drive via Google API

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-api

Let's say I have this minimal XML file on Google Drive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyCounter>
  <counter>137</counter>
</MyCounter>
```

Using Google Script, I want to:

1. parse the XML
2. add 1 to the counter
3. update the file.

I'm at step 2 at the moment. I can delete the old file and create a new one with the same name and updated content. I prefer to update the existing one instead, so it will maintain the unique ID, and I can access the file with said ID instead of searching for it via file name.

Comment: It is possible to achieve it. Can you provide the information of language you are using?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Google Apps Script. Added to the post

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not what you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to update a text file in your Google Drive without changing the file ID.
- You want to add 1 to `137` of `<counter>137</counter>` in the file.
- You want to achieve above using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve data from the text file.
2. Add 1 to `number` of `<counter>{number}</counter>` using `replace()`.
3. Update the file using `setContent()`.

By this flow, the file can be updated without changing file ID.

#### Sample script:

```
var fileId = "#####"; // Please set fileId here.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var str = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
var r = str.replace(/<counter>(\d+)<\/counter>/, function(_, p) {
  return "<counter>" + (Number(p) + 1) + "</counter>";
});
file.setContent(r);
```

#### Note:

- If you have already prepared the script for adding the counter, please use it.

#### References:

- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [setContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setcontentcontent)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm going to test it in a couple of days. By the way, this can do the trick for this minimal sample file (and, for the moment, it's what i need). I hoped to get an "XML-based" solution instead of a text-based one, so it can be easily scaled to more complicated XML.

Comment: Tested your script. It does the job, thanks! Soon I'll need to do something more  articulated, awfully...

Comment: @il_mix Thank you for confirming it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If you posted new question of the issue that you had when you use more complicated XML, I would like to also check it.